# C# XML Serialization - Custom ordering based on data

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I receive an XML file like this:

```
<ToDoList>
  <WakeUp Order="1">
  <Eat    Order="2" What="Breakfast">
  <Work   Order="3">
  <Eat    Order="4" What="Lunch">
  <Work   Order="5">
  <Eat    Order="6" What="Dinner">
  <Sleep  Order="7">
</ToDoList>
```

After deserializing this XML and processing the task(s), I need to serialize it back again and swap out some of the elements (for example, skipping lunch changes the middle "Eat" to "Skip"):

```
<ToDoList>
  <WakeUp Order="1">
  <Eat    Order="2" What="Breakfast">
  <Work   Order="3">
  <Skip   Order="4" What="Lunch">
  <Work   Order="5">
  <Eat    Order="6" What="Dinner">
  <Sleep  Order="7">
</ToDoList>
```

However, the C# XML serialization wants to group elements together so all the "Eat" elements are together, etc... I know that I can use the [XmlElement(Order = #)] attribute to specify a custom order, but that just changes the order of the groups. I'm trying to figure out how to tell the serializer to use the "Order" attribute from the data model instead of hard-coding the Order in XmlElement.

Conceptually, I'm looking for something like this:

```
[XmlElement(Order = Item.Order.Value)] <------
public List<Item> ToDoList { get; set; }
```

...or an ordering callback. I've checked through the XML serialization docs on MSDN but I'm not finding anything like this. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the items `<WakeUp>`, `<Eat    Order="2" What="Breakfast">`, `<Work   Order="3">` and so on all represented by the *same* class/schema, or by some *different* class/schema for each specific item type?  Also, is the `Order="X"` in the XML actually redundant, as the order is also given by order in the XML file itself?

Comment: At the moment, different class for each type.

Comment: Then the approach of using a polymorphic list as shown in [Keep sort when deserialize and serialize XML using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48096673/3744182) and [Xml Deserialization - Merging two elements into a single `List<T>` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37309127/3744182) should work.  Do those answer your question, or do you need a more specific answer?

Comment: I think the first example should work. Thank you!

Comment: Close as a duplicate then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep sort when deserialize and serialize XML using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096673/keep-sort-when-deserialize-and-serialize-xml-using-xmlserializer)